# Crontab to delete files

Tags: linux, cron, delete-file

I´m very new to Linux, and right now I am trying to delete some video recordings of my security camera (from the FTP server) at every 30 minutes.

I already used: `pi@raspberrypi:~$ find path/toMy/Video/recordings/ -type f -mmin +30 -delete`

After that, I used `crontab -e` choose the Nano option and typed:

`*/30 * * * * find path/toMy/Video/recordings/ -type f -mmin +30 -delete`

Saved it, but it doesn´t seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the full path to `find`, for example:

```
% which find
/usr/local/opt/findutils/libexec/gnubin/find
```

Also, use absolute path (not relative path) for your directory.

Then:

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/local/opt/findutils/libexec/gnubin/find /path/toMy/Video/recordings/ -type f -mmin +30 -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug:

1. You can also redirect the output of your crontab entry.

```
*/30 * * * * find path/toMy/Video/recordings/ -type f -mmin +30 -delete &> /<your-path>/cron.out
```

2. Check for the cron logs in `/var/log/`

Answer (score 0):

You should consider saving output of cron in a file to debug or simply try to run the command in terminal to see output. To save output of cron in file you can try:

```
*/30 * * * * command >/home/user/cron.log 2>&1
```